# Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.Maven.plugins: Maven-surefire-plugin: jar:3.0.0-M3:

Tags: maven

I have just created Maven project and running pom.xml as Maven test. But I am stuck due to this above error. FYI, there are no tests present, just I have created new Maven project. I tried all the option mentioned above by other users but it not working for me (Update, adding plugins etc.

Complete error: "Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:3.0.0-M3: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:3.0.0-M3 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Received fatal alert: protocol_version -> [Help 1]"

[image]

Comment: Please build on plain command line and take a deeper look into the log cause I suppose there is.a network/firewall issue... ?

Comment: Hi.. thanks for your reply..yes when i run it from command line (mvn install or mvn clean install) then build is success. But just for my knowledge i want to understand why it's failing when running through eclipse using (run as > maven test or run as > maven install). It always throw error for surefire. Earlier my pom.xml doesn't had sure fire plugin, when it gave the error then i added the plugin as mentioned  in my above screenshot for it but still i am receiving error. Can someone please share his/her thoughts or experience on this issue.

Comment: Ah..seen that you are using JDK 7 which means you have to configure jdk 7 to correctly to connect to central via TLSv1.2 cause central is https only https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041287334-Central-501-HTTPS-Required